# gulp-ruby-sass plugin not throwing error, only logging the error itself

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, sass, gulp

On the page for gulp ruby sass https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ruby-sass/

It says "Handle Sass errors with an on('error', cb) listener. gulp-ruby-sass throws errors like a gulp plugin, but streams the erroring files so you can see Sass errors in your browser too."

Then I should be able to log the error that it says it throws but when an error happens it is logged to the console and my error callback is never invoked, this is my code:

```
gulp.task("css", function() {

   return sass(paths.css.in)
          .on('error', logError)
          .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css.out));

});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's the error you're trying to log? If it's a quick fix I can help here, otherwise let's move it to the issue tracker.

Comment: Just general sass to css compilation errors. The plugin page states that it will throw errors and that they can be handled with the error event. But when I force a syntax error, the error gets logged to the console by the implementation code of the sass plugin and no error is ever thrown and thus my logError handler in the code never gets invoked. It's a shame because I call the useful gutil.beep method in my generic error handler to notify. The sass plugin does not notify when there's an error, but logs to the console silently.

Comment: Thank you, could you do that? I don't use github, also I'm running this on windows 7 if it makes any difference

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed this today actually. Use the `emitCompileError` option in version 1.3.0.

Note we can't log specific errors because:

- Sass doesn't output them as errors, just as stderr and stdout depending on whether you're compiling a single file or a directory
- node.js stderr and stdout message lines are not guaranteed to be made available in the group they were originally emitted in, so we can't parse the output reliably. https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1715#issuecomment-98213569

I may do some behind the scenes line-by-line parsing to fix this in the future.

For more info see the gulp-ruby-sass readme and the issue https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/issues/209.

Comment: Thank you! It works with that option yes.

I digged around in gulp-ruby-sass/logger.js

On line 40: gutil.log(data);

The compilation errors are logged through there as you know.

Is it not reliable to add another "else if" clause before the "else" and check the "data" variable output message for the string "Invalid CSS" and emit the error event on the stream if so? That string seems to be output in all compilation error.

    else if (/Invalid CSS/.test(data))
    {stream.emit("error", new Error(data));
}

Comment: We could. I got a little worried about parsing stdout/err after I found this behavior: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1715#issuecomment-98213569

Comment: But I don't think we're going to get away from using the command line executable, which displays the broken output issue. We can throw errors during the task, but not with reliably good error messages. I'm going to look at this again after the next group of issues I take care of.